# Google Apps Script CardService.setContent as HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am using CardService in my Google Scripts Adds-On. I am trying to `setContent` as HTML for that I am reading it from **Index.html**. But while rendering it's printing **CSS** and **Javascript** as text rather then using it in Html content.

```
function buildPage() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').getContent();
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('How do you feel ...'));
  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
    .setHeader("<h4>What do you want? </h4>");

  section.addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue()
    .setTopLabel('choose one')
    .setContent(html)
);
```

This is my `Index.html`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <base target="_top">
       <style>
           #things {
             position: absolute;
             top: 50%;
             left: 50%;
             color: green;
             margin-right: -50%;
             text-align: center;
          }
       </style>
     </head>
     <body>
       <p>List of things:</p>
       <ul id="things">
         <li>Loading...</li>
       </ul>

       <script
         src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
       </script>
       <script>
       // The code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
       $(function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showThings)
        .getLotsOfThings();
       });

       function showThings(things) {
         var list = $('#things');
         list.empty();
         for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
           list.append('<li>' + things[i] + '</li>');
         }
      }
      </script>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 5):

GMail Add-Ons only support very basic html style.

See https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/widgets#text_formatting

Comment: This answer actually makes sense, not sure why down voted?

Answer (score 3):

`setContent()` takes text and supports basic html formatting. I think it'll not support full html tags like styles, script etc

**Reference**
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/key-value#setcontenttext

Comment: Is there anything else that supports the scripts and styles. All I want is display the content, it need not be necessarily via the KeyValue.

Comment: I think that should be a new question :p

Comment: @JaiPrak The reason why Google abstracted away building UI for Gmail Add-ons is to make add-ons look consistent on all platforms, including mobile.  Not to mention multiple security concerns associated with injecting JavaScript into Gmail.